# How to import from excel into a 2d numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to import the below data (excel file) into a 2D numpy array

```
x1 | x2
12 | 56
34 | 89
43 | 10
34 | 11
```

My Python code:

```
spreadsheet = 'zone.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(spreadsheet)
x = data['x1'].values
y = data['x2'].values

x_train = np.concatenate((x,y))
```

The problem is that the output for `x_train` is `[12, 34, 43, 34, 56, 89, 10, 11]` and I would like to get the following output:

```
[[12, 56], [34, 56], [43,10], [34,11]]
```

Comment: have u tried concatenating without the `.values`

Comment: Yes. When I check the `.shape`, the result is `(8,)`. I want to get `(4, 2,2)` as `.shape`

Comment: `data.values` or `data.to_numpy()`?

Comment: data.values, but It works now. Check ombk's answeer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(-1,1)
y= np.array([2,3,4]).reshape(-1,1)
np.concatenate([x,y],axis=1)

#output

array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4]])
```

```
np.concatenate([x,y],axis=1).tolist()
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: It worked, first I transformed my Python label into a numpy array, then the `reshape` method worked. Thank you

Comment: @Viorel great ^_^

Comment: @Viorel accept answer to remove it from unanswered questions queue! thanks!